# Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem is equivalent to monotone class theorem

Tags: measure-theory, monotone-class-theorem

Let $\Omega$ be a set. Let $a(C), \lambda(C), m(C)$ be the smallest [algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets#Definitions), the smallest [$\lambda$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Definitions), and the smallest [monotone class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Definition_of_a_monotone_class) that contain $C$ respectively.

- [Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Dynkin%27s_%CF%80-%CE%BB_theorem) Let $C, D$ be a [$\pi$-system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-system#Definitions) and a $\lambda$-system on $\Omega$ respectively. If $C \subset D$ then $\sigma(C) \subset D$.
- [Monotone class theorem:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_class_theorem#Monotone_class_theorem_for_sets) Let $C$ be an algebra on $\Omega$. Then $m(C) = \sigma(C)$.

I'm trying to prove that the monotone class theorem is equivalent to Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem. Could you please have a check on my attempt?

**My attempt:**

- Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem $\implies$ Monotone class theorem:

Clearly, $\sigma(C)$ is a monotone class containing $C$, so $m(C) \subset \sigma(C)$. It remains to prove $\sigma(C) \subset m(C)$. Because $C$ is an algebra, it is a $\pi$-system. By Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, it suffices to prove $m(C)$ is a $\lambda$-system. It is indeed true by the following lemma 1, i.e.,

> [Lemma 1:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537114/let-g-be-an-algebra-then-the-smallest-monotone-class-containing-g-coincides) Let $C$ be an algebra on $\Omega$. Then $m(C) = \lambda(C)$.

- Monotone class theorem $\implies$ Dynkin's $\pi-\lambda$ theorem:

We have $\sigma(C) = \sigma(a(C))$. By monotone class theorem, we get $\sigma(a(C)) = m(a(C))$. By lemma 1, $m(a(C)) = \lambda(a(C))$. It suffices to prove that $\lambda(a(C)) \subset \lambda(C)$. However, it is true by the following lemma 2, i.e.,

> [Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537337/the-collection-lambdac-is-a-monotone-class-if-c-a-pi-system-then-a) The collection $\lambda(C)$ is a monotone class. If $C$ a $\pi$-system, then $a(C) \subset \lambda (C)$.